# How to use PageTitleStrategy with provideRouter in a standalone main.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

How can we provide our own page title strategy in a standalone main.ts, similar to how we provide a page title strategy using modules?

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: MyTitleStrategy, useClass: PageTitleStrategy }
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

To use PageTitleStrategy in a standalone application you can provide it on bootstrap applications providers array

**main.ts**

```ts
const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    { provide: TitleStrategy, useClass: MyTitleStrategy },
  ],
};

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```